# Is it possible to have one create page that is linked with 4 SQL tables in ASP.NET to make it more user friendly?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using C#, MVC and Entity Framework to create a website that will display and input data into a Vehicles database. So far I have a create page for each table controller. Is it possible to have one create page that will display and allow a user to enter data without having to go to each different create page for the controllers? This is what I am looking for. However because its just a view that I created in SQL Server Express it is a read only and I can't write to it.

This is what I want to accomplish so that way entering data is more user friendly

[image: Create Page For My SQL View With Table Joins]

This is what it looks like when I bring up the index page from my VehicleView Controller

[image: Index View]

This is where and how I created my view so that the user only sees the information they are looking for.

[image: SQL Join View]

Here is my code from the VehicleViewController

```
namespace VehiclesFinal.Controllers
{
    public class VehiclesViewsController : Controller
    {
        private DataConnection db = new DataConnection();

        // GET: VehiclesViews
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.VehiclesViews.ToList());
        }

        // GET: VehiclesViews/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            VehiclesView vehiclesView = db.VehiclesViews.Find(id);
            if (vehiclesView == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(vehiclesView);
        }

        // GET: VehiclesViews/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: VehiclesViews/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "VehicleId,Year,Price,Cost,Name,Model,Type,EngineSize,Transmission,NumberOfDoors,Colour,SoldDate")] VehiclesView vehiclesView)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.VehiclesViews.Add(vehiclesView);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(vehiclesView);
        }

        // GET: VehiclesViews/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            VehiclesView vehiclesView = db.VehiclesViews.Find(id);
            if (vehiclesView == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(vehiclesView);
        }

        // POST: VehiclesViews/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "VehicleId,Year,Price,Cost,Name,Model,Type,EngineSize,Transmission,NumberOfDoors,Colour,SoldDate")] VehiclesView vehiclesView)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(vehiclesView).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(vehiclesView);
        }

        // GET: VehiclesViews/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            VehiclesView vehiclesView = db.VehiclesViews.Find(id);
            if (vehiclesView == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(vehiclesView);
        }

        // POST: VehiclesViews/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            VehiclesView vehiclesView = db.VehiclesViews.Find(id);
            db.VehiclesViews.Remove(vehiclesView);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, it is possible.  Create a view model with all the data fields you want on it.  Populate the view model, send it to the view.  Allow editing of the fields and throw a save button on their.  Form post it all back to the controller.  In the controller action you'll need to do multiple saves to update each of the tables but that's no big deal.

Comment: So since I already have a controller for my view, I would just need to figure out a way to get the changes saved to the controllers action of the 4 different tables?

Comment: You don't need a separate controller for each database table.  For example, an AccountController would handle everything about the user and their account, which could span several tables.  In your controller action you should (if you set the form up correctly etc) get everything you need to know.  Then you make the appropriate changes to the models based on the updated info and do a db save.  That is all Entity Framework functionality.